# dmesg is not showing printk statement

Tags: linux-kernel, procfs

I'm trying to create a proc entry.
My init_module function is as below

```
int init_module()
{
printk(KERN_INFO "proc2:Module Loaded\n");
proc_entry=proc_create_data(proc_name,0644,NULL,&fops,NULL);
if(proc_entry==NULL)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "proc2:Error registering proc entry");
}
else
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "proc2:Proc Entry Created");
}
return 0;
}
```

following is cleanup method

```
void cleanup_module()
{
printk(KERN_INFO "proc2:module unloaded");
remove_proc_entry(proc_name,proc_entry);
}
```

rest of program include variable definition and callback functions.

when i compile this program it compiles well.
when i use `insmod` it doesn't reply me prompt.
`lsmod` lists my module and shows used by one (don't know what).
`dmesg` shows none of the above printk messages.

can you tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `echo "7" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` to enable all console log levels.

The numbers are corresponding to below:

```
#define KERN_EMERG "<0>" /* system is unusable*/
#define KERN_ALERT "<1>" /* action must be taken immediately*/
#define KERN_CRIT "<2>" /* critical conditions*/
#define KERN_ERR "<3>" /* error conditions*/
#define KERN_WARNING "<4>" /* warning conditions*/
#define KERN_NOTICE "<5>" /* normal but significant condition*/
#define KERN_INFO "<6>" /* informational*/
#define KERN_DEBUG "<7>" /* debug-level messages*/
```

The default number is 4, which allows console to show messages only at least in `KERN_WARNING`.
That's why you cannot see log in `KERN_INFO` level.

Comment: surprisingly not only KERN_INFO message. but whole module started working by using echo "7" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk

Comment: Because "7" allows all kinds of log from KERN_DEBUG to KERN_EMERG been shown, not only KERN_INFO specific.

Comment: I just want to add that it only succeeds if the user is root. The redirection would fail otherwise. The redirection can be replaced with a `| sudo tee` to make it work.

Comment: @russoue: Or `sudo sh -c 'echo 7 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk'`

Answer (score 3):

Even after using `echo "7" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk`, `printk` didn't worked for me.

https://lwn.net/Articles/487437/ says about modified or more enhanced version of `printk` called `pr_**` api's (`pr_info`,`pr_emerg`).

I used `pr_info` instead of `printk` and it solved my problem.

Comment: Not even `pr_info()` works for me :( I put it in `do_tcp_getsockopt()` then executed a `wget` to public www site.

Comment: This answer only adds confusion. `pr_info` is a macro to `printk(KERN_INFO, ...`. You also didn't include your code (Is it missing `KERN_INFO`, or maybe there's some other problem), so it's just guesswork to any reader.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Wayne's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18607526/2251364), the [kernel source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/printk.h#L416) says

> This macro expands to dynamic_pr_debug() if CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG is
> set. Otherwise, if DEBUG is defined, it's equivalent to a printk with
> KERN_DEBUG loglevel. If DEBUG is not defined it does nothing.

Which means you'd need to either define `DEBUG` or use [dynamic debug](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.12/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html).
I was able to successfully load the module with debug printk via

```
$ sudo insmod module-name.ko dyndbg
```