# How can I find my system call is added to kernel?

Tags: c, linux

I have added a hello world system call to Linux kernel 3.16, then I compile and ran it. I called my system call by `syscall` function but it did not print any thing and output of `syscall` function was not -1.

This is my system call code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>

asmlinkage long sys_hello(void){
    printk("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and this my c program code to call my system call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void){
    printf("function\n");
    if(syscall(317)==-1){
        printf("no\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("yes\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of c program is:

```
function
yes
```

How can I find my system call is added to kernel correctly?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the execution with a tool like strace ?

Comment: i did not know dmesg. it tried dmesg and its worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printk` wouldn't necessarily print to your current tty; to see your message use the `dmesg` command in your shell. See also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607184/dmesg-is-not-showing-printk-statement) if it does not show up on  `dmesg`

Comment: thank you so much, it worked. if i want to know my system call is added to kernel without running its function, what can i do?