# How to remove a message from watchdog when I close /dev/watchdog file

Tags: embedded-linux, safety-critical

I use a hardware watchdog to monitor an activity of some process and reboot the system in case the process is hanged.

While the system is executing init.d scripts a watchdog utility is running. Later, the process mentioned earlier is taking control over the watchdog so the watchdog utility have to be closed.
At this moment I would like to not see any messages about watchdog in my log:

```
[   72.672542] watchdog: watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
```

A watchdog which automatically stops when file is closed is not a real watchdog, so, of course the kernel is built with NOWAYOUT option on purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct and crude solution which I've found useful is to make a patch for `drivers/watchdog/watchdog_dev.c` file to remove the annoying line of code.

Comment: It's not an answer as what you are doing is completely wrong. The message is critical and it's correct. You have some users of the watchdog that should stop it before exiting. So, either the user space code is incorrect or the driver of your watchdog device, there is nothing to fix in the mentioned file.

Comment: There are no users other than the mentioned process. Yes, it runs from user space. But it is an application dispatcher and it must have exclusive access to watchdog by design. If it crashes or exits - the system must restart and this dispatcher must run again.

Comment: A non-disablable or at least password-protected watchdog is one of the main piles of functional safety. And the way Linux treats it is just disgraceful!

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
echo "2" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

Also removed others messages.
To return default:

```
echo "7" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

also see:

[dmesg is not showing printk statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607184/dmesg-is-not-showing-printk-statement)